# How to align a Text field and a button field in hfm in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, horizontalfieldmanager

I want to add a TextField and a ButtonField to a  HorizontalFieldManager. Now, I am using the following code

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfmFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL  | USE_ALL_WIDTH);
hfmFieldManager.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);

VerticalFieldManager buttonFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH |  Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
ButtonField btnDone = new ButtonField("DONE", FIELD_VCENTER  | Field.FIELD_RIGHT);
btnDone.setMargin(0, MARGIN, 0, MARGIN);
buttonFieldManager.add(btnDone);

TextField txtField = new TextField(FIELD_VCENTER | FIELD_LEFT)/*{
    protected  void layout(int width, int height) {
        super.layout((int) (Display.getWidth() * 0.5) , getPreferredHeight());
    }
}*/;
txtField.setBorder(roundedBorder);
txtField.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
hfmFieldManager.add(txtField);
hfmFieldManager.add(buttonFieldManager);
```

But it shows TextField Only. I want to show buttonfield completely at the right side and the remaining left side for textField.(Show TextField,Buttonfield from left to right).

How can i adjust the width of textfield which is compatible for all screen sizes?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will have to create your own Manager to do this.  As a starting point, look at the Managers in here :  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276 and also review this : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager j=new JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager(your_text_field,your_button_field, true);
```

then add the field to your screen.

//JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager class is given below

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;

public class JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager extends Manager
{
    private static final int SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT = 32;

    public Field _leftField;
    public Field _rightField;

    private boolean _giveLeftFieldPriority;

    public JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( Field leftField, Field rightField, boolean giveLeftFieldPriority )
    {
        this( leftField, rightField, giveLeftFieldPriority, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH );
    }

    public JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( Field leftField, Field rightField, boolean giveLeftFieldPriority, long style )
    {
        super( style );

        _leftField = leftField;
        _rightField = rightField;

        add( _leftField );
        add( _rightField );

        _giveLeftFieldPriority = giveLeftFieldPriority;
    }


    public JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( boolean giveLeftFieldPriority, long style )
    {
        super( style ); 
        _giveLeftFieldPriority = giveLeftFieldPriority;
    }

    public void addLeftField( Field field )
    {
        if( _leftField != null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        _leftField = field;
        add( _leftField );
    }

    public void addRightField( Field field )
    {
        if( _rightField != null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        _rightField = field;
        add( _rightField );
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth()
    {
        return _leftField.getPreferredWidth() + _rightField.getPreferredWidth();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight()
    {
        return Math.max( _leftField.getPreferredHeight(), _rightField.getPreferredHeight() );
    }

    protected void sublayout( int width, int height )
    {
        Field firstField;
        Field secondField;
        if( _giveLeftFieldPriority ) {
            firstField = _leftField;
            secondField = _rightField;
        } else {
            firstField = _rightField;
            secondField = _leftField;
        }

        int maxHeight = 0;

        int availableWidth = width;
        availableWidth -= _leftField.getMarginLeft();
        availableWidth -= Math.max( _leftField.getMarginRight(), _rightField.getMarginLeft() );
        availableWidth -= _rightField.getMarginRight();

        layoutChild( firstField, availableWidth, height - firstField.getMarginTop() - firstField.getMarginBottom() );
        maxHeight = Math.max( maxHeight, firstField.getMarginTop() + firstField.getHeight() + firstField.getMarginBottom() );
        availableWidth -= firstField.getWidth();

        layoutChild( secondField, availableWidth, height - secondField.getMarginTop() - secondField.getMarginBottom() );
        maxHeight = Math.max( maxHeight, secondField.getMarginTop() + secondField.getHeight() + secondField.getMarginBottom() );
        availableWidth -= secondField.getWidth();

        if( !isStyle( Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT ) ) {
            height = maxHeight;
        }
        if( !isStyle( Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH ) ) {
            width -= availableWidth;
        }

        setPositionChild( _leftField, _leftField.getMarginLeft(), getFieldY( _leftField, height ) );
        setPositionChild( _rightField, width - _rightField.getWidth() - _rightField.getMarginRight(), getFieldY( _rightField, height ) );

        setExtent( width, height );
    }

    private int getFieldY( Field field, int height )
    {
        switch( (int)( ( field.getStyle() & FIELD_VALIGN_MASK ) >> SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT ) ) {
            case (int)( FIELD_BOTTOM >> SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT ):
                return height - field.getHeight() - field.getMarginBottom();
            case (int)( FIELD_VCENTER >> SYSTEM_STYLE_SHIFT ):
                return field.getMarginTop() + ( height - field.getMarginTop() - field.getHeight() - field.getMarginBottom() ) / 2;
            default:
                return field.getMarginTop();
        }
    }


    public Field getLeftField()
    {
        return _leftField;
    }

    public Field getRightField()
    {
        return _rightField;
    }

    public void replace( Field oldField, Field newField )
    {
        if( oldField == newField ) {
            // Nothing to do
            return;
        }

        if( oldField == _leftField ) {
            _leftField = newField;
        } else if( oldField == _rightField ) {
            _rightField = newField;
        }
        add( newField );
        delete( oldField );
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this one of the samples included in the Advanced UI samples, I pointed to above (http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)? I think the original sample can be found here: https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/container/JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager.java